# Django ORM: Implementing many-to-many relation with postgresql array

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

What's the best to way implement many-to-many relation with postgresql array field in Django. (Suppose M-N relationship between Post and Category, we can save id's of related categories in a single array field for each post)

I search for a way (or library) compatible with other parts of django ORM (specially admin site). For example django can display vertical/horizontal widgets for many-to-many fields, or inline related objects, or ....).

Comment: FWIW: M2M relationship requires a separate table. In your way, you'll need a field called posts in category table and a field called categories in post table. And you lose the scope to have additional attributes for the relationship. It's not really M2M. You're just implementing One to Many from both side. I wonder why you want to do that.

Comment: Postgresql offers GIN index over arrays, so posts can also queried by category in reverse direction.

Comment: It's rarely better to use arrays rather than a m:n join table for this.

Comment: If you're using Arrays for relationship, then don't call it relationship. You can create a new field like any other field and query it. Like having an enum field having IDs of records from another table. It's not a traditional DB relationship. You need to implement it with your own business logic.